# C++: Large dynamic array of structs that rarely changes size, Is Vector necessary?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, struct, stdvector

I have many large arrays of structs, and the size of the array will rarely ever change in max size, and when it does, it's acceptable.

I figure I should have one big allocated block that I can keep writing and rewriting the following struct to:

```
struct S{
    unsigned int A;
    unsigned int B;
};
```

In memory, an array of 3 of these structs should have this layout:

```
A,B,A,B,A,B.
```

And not:

```
*A,*B,*A,*B,*A,*B.
```

Nor should it be a linked list, as I don't need to know when one entry ends and the next begins. All my entries are the same size, and will never amount to more than what I've allocated in a large block. There are also a huge number of entries, so as little overhead in each element as possible is important. Some overhead per array/vector/list is fine, though.

I've seen suggestions to use `std::vector`, but from what I gather, it has some overhead per element that I don't need in this case.

What should I be using here? If a dynamic array is proper, can I just:

```
S* arr = new S[x];
```

but also have this show up as an array in the debugger?

Comment: `std::vector` has no overhead per element.

Comment: There's "overhead" in debug mode and depending on what you're using it for (and how you're using it).  You could compromise and use a std::array of course.

Comment: `std::array` only makes sense if the size is fixed, as it is part of the type (and thus static).

Comment: @Robinson there's no per object memory overhead though. There's 'good' overhead of bounds and iterator checks in a non-optimised build, but those builds are slow anyway.

Comment: Daniel, he states, "all my entries are the same size, and will never amount to more than what I've allocated in a large block" - so in theory he can use std::array if he wants, though he has to manage his free space manually (again depending on how he's actually using it).

Comment: since size is fixed  , you can provide this size in vector constuctor to optimise it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::vector` has zero overhead per element, and is essentially a dynamic array à la `new S[n]`, without the hassle. It is definitely the right tool here.

Note that for best performance when constructing the vector, you can use [`reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve).